# Dynamic ListView Android (autodetecting the end)

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I'd like to make a listview that, initially shows some elements of an array, loading more entries when you scroll down as maket does in example.
Can someone help me with or link solving that? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh for one possible solution, and https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless for another.